# Redirect all files of a type with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, regex-negation

I'm cleaning up my web space and I have moved all PDFs from the top directory to a lower level one. I'd like to redirect so that the old URLs still work. What I have so far is

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.pdf$ http://example.com/uploads/papers/$1.pdf
```

The problem is that this also redirects something like http://example.com/uploads/papers/paper.pdf to http://example.com/uploads/papers//uploads/papers/paper.pdf and so on, resulting in infinite redirects.

I've tried excluding forward slashes from the matches, or the word "uploads", but without success.

Answer (score 1):

If the PDFs were previously located at root `/` only

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)\.pdf$ http://mysite.com/uploads/papers/$1.pdf
```

Or, inside `/uploads` for example; but some single directory

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/uploads/([^/]+)\.pdf$ http://mysite.com/uploads/papers/$1.pdf
```

If the PDFs could be located anywhere then you need to put a conditional rule as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/papers/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.pdf$ /uploads/papers/$1.pdf [NC,L]
```

The conditional rule above assumes you have your `.htaccess` located at web root `/` directory.

Comment: The first two still send me into a redirect loop – no idea why. The third solution works. Maybe worth noting that you need to switch `RewriteEngine On` before, in case someone has the same problem and finds this solution.

Comment: Where are the old pdf links pointing to? If root can you try with `^/` added to the match.